# looking for a cli workflow

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a command-line utility (nix based - mac os) that will allow the following:

"associate" files together under a "label", files might come from different directories, then

list label

would show a list of files under the label.

Also be able to associate files together - might be a pdf files with associated note files, again one pdf might want multiple note files associated with it, or a single note file might be associated with multiple pdf files (in different directories). Again a way to list a file and see all associated files, then open them.

Would tags and some kind of terminal based file manager work for this?

Comment: because links are one-way this doesn't exactly answer the question, but I've always just used directories full of symlinks to tag my art collection

Comment: It honestly sounds like a directory structure and/or a consistent file naming scheme may do this or you.